# URL output of my code is not correct

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, shopify

I am using Shopify, and with current code I would like to redirect users to the correct URL based on their choice in the dropdown.

I wrote this code for the dropdown:

```
    <ul class="clearfix filters">
    <li class="clearfix filter">
    <label>Shop by color</label>
    <select class="coll-filter">
    <option value="/collections/all">All</option>
    {% for col in collections %}
    <option value="{{ col.url }}"{% if collection.handle == col.handle %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ col.title }}</option>
{% endfor %}
    </select>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

And this is the script for the above dropdown (collection is like category):

```
<script>
  Shopify.queryParams = {};
  if (location.search.length) {
    for (var aKeyValue, i = 0, aCouples = location.search.substr(1).split('&'); i < aCouples.length; i++) {
      aKeyValue = aCouples[i].split('=');
      if (aKeyValue.length > 1) {
        Shopify.queryParams[decodeURIComponent(aKeyValue[0])] = decodeURIComponent(aKeyValue[1]);
      }
    }
  }
  var collFilters = jQuery('.coll-filter');
  collFilters.change(function() {
      var newTags = [];
      var newURL = '';
      collFilters.each(function() { 
        if (jQuery(this).val()) {
          newTags.push(jQuery(this).val());
        }
      });
      {% if collection.handle %}
      newURL = '{{ collection.handle }}';
      if (newTags.length) {
        newURL += '/' + newTags.join('+');
      }
      var search = jQuery.param(Shopify.queryParams);
      if (search.length) {
        newURL += '?' + search;
      }
      location.href = newURL;    
      {% else %}
      if (newTags.length) {
        Shopify.queryParams.constraint = newTags.join('+');        
      }
      else {
        delete Shopify.queryParams.constraint;
      }
      location.search = jQuery.param(Shopify.queryParams);
      {% endif %}      
  });

</script>
```

What the code does is that the output is:
http://domain.com/collections/all//collections/product

But I need that is:
http://domain.com/collections/product

The problem should be in this part (location.href = newURL;  ), but I cannot make it work like it should.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this would fix it:

```
 newURL = '/{{ collection.handle }}';
```

This makes your new url root relative; without the / your url is relative to the current url.